# ECP5 Versa Board Example

Tags: lattice

I'm struggling to get my design on the ECP5 Versa board running. Currently it's just for hardware verification so there's not much going on. So this is my top entity...

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;

USE work.config_package.ALL;

ENTITY top_entity IS
  PORT(
    SYSCLK        : IN    std_logic;
    CLKOUT        : OUT   std_logic;
    SOD           : OUT std_logic_vector(73 DOWNTO 0);
    ds            : IN std_logic_vector(5 downto 0)
  );

END ENTITY top_entity;

ARCHITECTURE rtl OF top_entity IS

  SIGNAL osc, clk_160m, clk_50m, clk_i, rst_i, clken_1MHz, clken_1kHz, led : std_logic;

  COMPONENT ECP5PLL IS
    PORT(CLKI  : IN  std_logic;
         CLKOP : OUT std_logic;
         CLKOS : OUT std_logic
        );
  END COMPONENT ECP5PLL;

  COMPONENT OSCG
  GENERIC (
     DIV   : Integer := 128 );
  PORT (
     OSC : OUT std_logic := 'X' );
  END COMPONENT;

  COMPONENT powerup_rst IS
    GENERIC(
      rst_time : IN integer := 5000     --100ms
    );
    PORT(
      clk_i     : IN  std_logic;
      rst_i     : IN  std_logic;
      force_rst : IN  std_logic;
      rst_o     : OUT std_logic;
      rst_n_o   : OUT std_logic
    );
  END COMPONENT powerup_rst;

  COMPONENT clockdivider_const
    GENERIC(
      div_value        : integer;
      reset_on_disable : boolean
    );
    PORT(
      clk_i      : IN  std_logic;
      rst_i      : IN  std_logic;
      enable     : IN  std_logic;
      clk_out_en : OUT std_logic;
      clk_out    : OUT std_logic
    );
  END COMPONENT clockdivider_const;

BEGIN

  SOD(0)  <= led;
  SOD(1)  <= '1';
  SOD(2)   <= '0';
  SOD(3)   <= '1';
  SOD(4)   <= '0';
  SOD(5)   <= '1';
  SOD(6)   <= ds(0);
  SOD(7)   <= '1';
  SOD(9)   <= '0';
  SOD(10)   <= '0';
  SOD(11)   <= '0';
  SOD(12)   <= '0';
  SOD(13)   <= '0';
  SOD(14)   <= '0';

  oscillator : OSCG
    GENERIC MAP (
       DIV    => 32 )
    PORT MAP(
       OSC  => osc 
     );

  ECP5PLL_inst : COMPONENT ECP5PLL
    PORT MAP(
      CLKI  => osc,
      CLKOP => clk_i,
      CLKOS => clk_50m
    );

  SOD(15)  <= clk_50m;
  SOD(SOD'left downto 16)  <= (OTHERS  => '0');

    -- Reset on power up
  u1_powerup_rst_inst : powerup_rst
    GENERIC MAP(
      rst_time => 50
    )
    PORT MAP(
      clk_i     => clk_i,
      rst_i     => '0',
      force_rst => '0',
      rst_o     => rst_i
    );

  FPGA_INT <= (OTHERS => '0');
  CLKOUT   <= clk_160m;

  -- Clockdivider for 1MHz clock
  u1_clockdivider_const_inst : clockdivider_const
    GENERIC MAP(
      reset_on_disable => true,
      div_value        => 160
    )

    PORT MAP(
      clk_i      => clk_i,
      rst_i      => rst_i,
      enable     => '1',
      clk_out    => OPEN,
      clk_out_en => clken_1MHz
    );

  -- Clockdivider for 1kHz clock
  u2_clockdivider_const_inst : clockdivider_const
    GENERIC MAP(
      reset_on_disable => true,
      div_value        => 1000
    )

    PORT MAP(
      clk_i      => clken_1MHz,
      rst_i      => rst_i,
      enable     => '1',
      clk_out    => OPEN,
      clk_out_en => clken_1kHz
    );
  
  u3_clockdivider_const_inst : clockdivider_const
    GENERIC MAP(
      reset_on_disable => true,
      div_value        => 1000
    )

    PORT MAP(
      clk_i      => clk_i,
      rst_i      => rst_i,
      enable     => clken_1kHz,
      clk_out    => led,
      clk_out_en => open
    );

END ARCHITECTURE rtl;
```

But beside of the static assignments, nothing works

so SOD(0) that should be flickering with approximately 1Hz is just statically '0' so it seems that the oscillator doesn't work. I first tried to use the external 100MHz oscillator but that also didn't work.
The PLL and the OSC component seem to be infered according to the build report

```
   OSC                1/1           100% used
   PLL                1/4            25% used
```

Another thing that puzzles me is the following message during synthesis

```
WARNING - I/O Port SOD[6] 's net has no driver and is unused.
```

But `SOD[6]`'s driver should be `ds[0]` which is assigned to the dip switch pin `H2`

[image]

This is the first time I'm using Diamond and the ECP5 and I don't know if I have to include something more in my project or if the usage of the library components is wrong. It's hard to find any reference for such a design.

Comment: Did u check the simulation of signal 'led' and if it's toggling at  every 1000 ms.

Comment: @MituRaj No, would I do that using ModelSim? Have to familiarize me with the tool then... but does it allow me to simulate Lattice IP blocks such as the `OSCG` and `PLL`?

Comment: Yea, Lattice Diamond should have support for third-party simulator like ModelSim,  where you just have to compile the libraries of lattice blocks. By the way, don't Lattice have its own simulation tool?

Comment: I think for simulation you need a testbench that replaces the clock IPs. Do I have to do any special clock distribution or is there a global reset I have to clear?

Comment: I'm still struggling with this, so if anyone has experience with the ECP5 or event better with the Versa board, please let me know.

Comment: Try asking EDAboard, they have good response for tool related queries.

Comment: I'll give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue has been resolved, as it turned out you explicitely need to add the corresponding chip library, in my case the one for the ECP5

```
library ecp5um;
use ecp5um.components.all;
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer to this issue, but where do you put this library reference if your code is in verilog instead of vhdl?
I am encountering the exact same problem with ECP5UM.

Comment: @JAM - Hi, I have converted your post into the comment above, so that it can be treated as a clarification question (which is allowed in comments on SE, but please read the [tour] & [help] to see how SE differs from typical forums and to see why your posting as an *answer* wasn't allowed). If the site member who kindly wrote this answer can clarify regarding the library reference then great. If not, then you will need to [ask a new question](/questions/ask). In that new question, you can link to [this question](/q/564799) for context, but the new question must be complete itself. Thanks.

Comment: @JAM Unfortunately I've never used verilog so I don't have an answer to your question